# Is there an Easter egg in the prison arrival scene with the woman watching a 3D family video?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, easter-egg

Saw a clip on YouTube of the GotG prison arrival scene. As the walk into the Common room of the prison, the camera pans across a woman watching a "family 3D video or maybe a live 3D video call"? (Man and two kids wave to female inmate)

[image: Possible Easter Egg?]

The scene seemed a bit focused on them, and I wondered if there was some Easter egg associated with the woman or the people in the video. Or if it was just a bit of background fluff.

Comment: It is reminiscent of the Star Wars R2-D2/Wokie 3D board game on the Millennium Falcon. ("Let the Wokie Win") But I was wondering if the people had any special significance.

Comment: There's nothing in the commentary.